# How to create a new FileList object without using DataTransfer()

Tags: javascript, data-transfer, filelist

I am creating an image uploader with image preview and the user can cancel/delete any image before submitting the form.

The problem is we can not modify the `FileList()` object till now without using the `DataTransfer()`. Unfortunately, DataTransfer() is not supported in iOS.

Just because of the `DataTransfer()` many existing plugins can not be used in production as we can not ignore iOS.

Is there any other way that I am missing to consider?

Thank You.